# trying to take text from one activity and print to text activity but it fails

Tags: android, android-intent

there is no error present in the code below, first activity works good,but on click  button it stops(crash)

help me about that

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
     b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent =new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class);
        intent.putExtra("thetv",et.getText().toString() );
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
}    
}

public class Second extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second) ;           
            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("thetv"));
}
}
```

logcat data

05-19 21:51:06.089: W/KeyCharacterMap(1561): No keyboard for id 0

05-19 21:51:06.089: W/KeyCharacterMap(1561): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin

05-19 21:51:15.659: D/AndroidRuntime(1561): Shutting down VM

05-19 21:51:15.659: W/dalvikvm(1561): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)

05-19 21:51:15.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1561): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

05-19 21:51:15.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1561): java.lang.NullPointerException

05-19 21:51:15.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1561):     at com.nav.activitieslearn.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:26)

05-19 21:51:15.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1561):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)

05-19 21:51:15.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1561):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)

05-19 21:51:15.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1561):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)

05-19 21:51:15.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1561):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

05-19 21:51:15.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1561):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

05-19 21:51:15.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1561):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)

05-19 21:51:15.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1561):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

05-19 21:51:15.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1561):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)

05-19 21:51:15.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1561):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)

05-19 21:51:15.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1561):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)

05-19 21:51:15.669: E/AndroidRuntime(1561):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

05-19 21:51:19.538: I/Process(1561): Sending signal. PID: 1561 SIG: 9

android manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.nav.activitieslearn.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.nav.activitieslearn.Second" >

    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: have you made an entry for Second Activity in   manifest file

Comment: make sure u have declared Second Activity in AndroidManifest.xml and plz add logcat results with question

Comment: make sure tv in second activity is not null!

Comment: publish the layout files :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check these lines,

In activity 1:

`final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);`

In activity 2:

`TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);`

It should be (I guess):

In activity 1:

`final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);`

In activity 2:

`TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);`

Try this correction and see whether it works or not.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the name of your `EditText` is not textView1.

Answer (score 0):

**Activity 1:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Activity1 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.one);

         Intent intent =new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
            intent.putExtra("Key","Sringtosecondactivity" );
            startActivity(intent);

    }

}
```

**Activity2**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Activity2 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       System.out.println("EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEe "+getIntent().getExtras().getString("Key"));


    }
}
```

Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rajesh.one"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".Activity1" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".Activity2" >
            </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```